# Using multiple threads to unblock network calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency

For simplification purposes, let's suppose I'm downloading multiple large files from S3 to my local machine.

```
def get_file(name):
    # pull from S3 and returns DataFrame
    return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df1 = get_file("large_file_1.csv")
    df2 = get_file("large_file_2.csv")
    df3 = get_file("large_file_3.csv")
```

and I want to refactor this code to make these calls non-blocking (i.e. start pulling all of them from S3 at once and wait for them to finish). My first instinct is to use the threading module with something like

```
from threading import Thread

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = Thread(target=get_file, args=("large_file_1.csv",))
    t2 = Thread(target=get_file, args=("large_file_2.csv",))
    t3 = Thread(target=get_file, args=("large_file_3.csv",))

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
```

However, `Thread` doesn't expose a way to assign the return value of the target function to a variable. What's the preferred way of going about this is in Python?

Comment: When it comes to downloading multiple large files I would recommend checking out [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and [`aiohttp`](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). You'll find that multithreading - while it works - might not be the most optimal way to do this. Asynchronous code would fit the task just as fast, and generally be more efficient for your machine. [Here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/2249#issuecomment-327896106) is an example of downloading a `10gb` file.

Comment: You can technically *pass an object by reference* to each of your threads and store values there for later reference. Either that or global structures can be used, but be careful there. The simplest solution is probably to use a dictionary with each key representing a thread ID and value representing the "return value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do the work concurrently, and get a response back from each thread, is to use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def get_file(f):
    # Do real work here
    return f + "1"  # Return a real result here

l = ["large_file_1.csv", "large_file_2.csv", "large_file3.csv"]
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(3)
out = pool.map(get_file, l)
print(list(out))
```

Output:

```
['large_file_1.csv1', 'large_file_2.csv1', 'large_file3.csv1']
```

You could also keep using `Thread` directly, and use a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue-objects) to get the results back, but `ThreadPoolExecutor` is abstracting that away for you, so there's really no need.